# reading corpus by python code for Arabic language

Tags: python, nltk

I want to read Arabic dictionary Bw and then extract some lexical items like "N" , "V" by Python. Also, I have Arabic Pen treebank I want to extract trigram from it. I am so new for using Python, where do I begin?

Comment: Can you share your attempt so far? This helps us figure out where you really need help. Right now, your question is difficult to understand and may be closed by the community.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one place to begin.

http://www.nltk.org/

Python is the most used tool for Natural Language processing and the community of academics who built and use the NLTK have probably already made a tool that will do most of what you need.

It is best to start out with a tutorial like this one, http://www.desilinguist.org/pdf/crossroads.pdf and work with a simple European language. Then when you are more familiar with the tools, start working with Arabic texts.